# "does not contain a definition and no accessible extension metho..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently builiding an ASP .NET MVC application but I'm getting this error in my program. Not really sure what I did wrong.

This is my model: ProfileCreationContext

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CRUD_Profile_Creation.Models
{
    public class ProfileCreationContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            var configuration = builder.Build();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:UserProfile"]);
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-HDBEK6R;Initial Catalog=Bottleneckv1;Integrated Security=True");

        public DbSet<ProcessUnit> ProcessUnit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my other model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRUD_Profile_Creation.Models
{
    public class ProcessUnit
    {
        public string ProcessUnitID { get; set; }   
        public string ProcessUnitName { get; set;}
        public int ProcessTypeID { get; set;}
        public string InventoryName { get; set;}
        public string CumM { get; set;}
        public string PerdayM { get; set;}
        public string TotalM { get; set; }
       
    }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
using CRUD_Profile_Creation.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRUD_Profile_Creation.Controllers
{
    public class ProcessUnitController : Controller
    {
        private ProfileCreationContext db = new ProfileCreationContext();
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.processUnitID = db.ProcessUnitID.ToList();
            ViewBag.processUnitID = db.ProcessUnitName.ToList();
            ViewBag.processUnitID = db.ProcessTypeID.ToList();
            ViewBag.processUnitID = db.InventoryName.ToList();
            ViewBag.processUnitID = db.CumM.ToList();
            ViewBag.processUnitID = db.PerdayM.ToList();
            ViewBag.processUnitID = db.TotalM.ToList();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting.
[image]

I'm still new in this framework. Im doing this based off my past personal projects

---

***THE SOLUTION I DID***

so basically, what I wanted was to list out all the items in the table. this is how I fixed it. I needed just to call that. Not sure why I started by listing all the variables. Hope this helps!

My controller:

```
public class DenoProfileController : Controller
{
    private ProfileCreationContext db = new ProfileCreationContext();

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.denoprofile = db.DenoProfile.ToList();         
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: `ProfileCreationContext`, indeed, does not contain any of that. `ProcessUnit` does.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to overwrite `ViewBag.processUnitID` 6 times either!

Comment: Best practice for ASP.NET MVC is not to use ViewBag (unless you really need to) and use a strongly typed model (the M in MVC)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was a bit confused. @phuzi, can you suggest other functions besides ViewBag?

Comment: @GSerg , I thought the DBSet will connect the two models together? Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Yep, you should probably create a new class specifically for the view, this is the M in MVC - the model. `var model = new MyViewModel();` then later `return View(model);`. In your view you then use `@model = <MyViewmdel's namespace>.MyViewModel` then you use @Model in your view.